# JFreeChart to Primefaces chart

Tags: primefaces, jfreechart

I am using static primefaces chart component:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{dynamicImageController.chart}" />
```

Is there any way how I can easily switch from this static image (jfree chart) to primefaces chart's model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes... checkout the primefaces docs: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dynamicImage.jsf (it evens shows you how to use jfreechart)

Comment: I think he want to build a primefaces chart's model , to interact with it and not an image.

Comment: You're probably right... my bad! I'll leave the answer there, though... just in case it helps someone else.

Comment: Maybe I was't clear enough. I already have a bunch of jfreecharts and I want to get rid of them and to switch on new primefaces charts components. The problem is that the whole model classes depend on jfreecharts' library (classes).

Comment: Fair enough... You probably have quite a bit of work ahead of you, I think. Just out of curiosity... why are you switching?

Comment: Because of ugly and old-fashioned design of jfreecharts :). If you compared it with new primefaces charts, the difference is obvious.